# How can I fix my header after upgrading to Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I changed my bootstrap files and now my `Navbar` has broken. I've been updating my code to match the docs on their website but I just can't figure out what i'm missing. I thought it was because this code needed updating.
The `Nav` is now under my header image

from

```
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-navbar-1">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
```

to

```
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data- 
     target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
```

I've made a codepen here - https://codepen.io/grabthereef/pen/pxGweE
Before I changed version it looked like this;

[image]

Comment: so before upgrading to bs-4 , your navbar was on top of the image ? or before the image ( placeholder 900x500 in codepen )

Comment: @MihaiT It was on top of the image that is in the picture I included in my question. So on the code pen it should be on top of the placeholder

Answer (score 1):

If you want the navbar to be on top of the image placeholders, you just need to add `fixed-top` css class to the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
```

**[Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xyMQzj)**

Documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/#placement

If you want to know what really went wrong, you need to also post the HTML **before** you migrated to bootstrap 4 so that we can see the differences?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but why do not just swap them:

```css
.blank-image {
  height: 500px;
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/900x500/888/fff');
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute !important;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  background: #000;
  border: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -o-transition: all .6s;
  -moz-transition: all .6s;
  -webkit-transition: all .6s;
  -ms-transition: all .6s;
  transition: all .6s;
  background-color: transparent !important;
}


.navbar-no-bg {
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: none;
}

ul.navbar-nav {
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav li a {
  color: #ddd;
  border: 0;
}

.navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
}

.navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav li a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  outline: 0;
  border: 0;
}


/* .navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav li a.btn-link-3 {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 9px 0 0 15px;
 padding: 6px 15px;
 background: #df6482;
 border: 0;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 300;
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 1;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; border-radius: 6px;
}
.navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav li a.btn-link-3:hover,
.navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav li a.btn-link-3:focus,
.navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav li a.btn-link-3:active,
.navbar-inverse ul.navbar-nav li a.btn-link-3:active:focus { 
 outline: 0; opacity: 0.6; color: #fff; 
} */

.navbar-brand {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff !important;
  /* text-indent: -99999px; */
}

.navbar>.container .navbar-brand,
.navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#top-navbar-1">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Navbar</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-navbar-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Take A Tour</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">What We Offer</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Rates</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="blank-image"></div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, if you look at my response to the user who commented above

Comment: Sorry about that @bonEte, I have updated the above snippet, adding a `position: absolute` and `width:100%` to the `.navbar`. More changes needs to be made in order to make it looks like your image, will you do that or do you need help?